# Template 10 WelcomePage & LoginPage

Tags: windows-10, win-universal-app, template10

i have Welcome Page, Login Page and the Main Page. I wanna have the welcome page and login outside the Shell. After the user login he will be redirected to Main Page that has the hamburger menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Page Navigation is the direction you want to go... Hamburger can be hidden using `IsFullScreen = true` then once you are sure they are "authenticated" from the login turn `IsFullScreen = false` off. So initially setup your navigation to Welcome page then login when appropriate.

```cs
public override async Task OnStartAsync(StartKind startKind, IActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    await NavigationService.NavigateAsync(typeof(Views.WelcomePage));
}
```

then in the `OnNavigationTo()` override in your  WelcomePageViewModel.cs
you will have a `IsFullScreen`, tells hamburger to be invisible.  Once ready to login you how ever you setup to move to your login screen.

**Edit**: `IsFullScreen` is part of the Shell but there is a property within the `SettingsService` within template10 that serializes the setting to "settings.dat" which is stored in the profile of the application.

```
Template10.Services.SettingService _settings = SettingService.Instance;
_settings.IsFullScreen
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That's what i currently have i was hoping if there was any better solution. Sorry for not specifying that i currently using this.